# How can I parse multiple forms of data from a file?

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, fgets, text-parsing

I apologize if there is a lot of information about this online... I don't know why, but I can't seem to piece everything together and it's frustrating me to no end.

I'm working on an assignment where I have to read data from a file (specified in a command-line argument), then create functions to parse data relative to that function into a dynamic two dimensional array.  I'm essentially supposed to create a grade report from this data.

The data set is formatted as such:

```
4
5
John Steve James Susan Emily
100 98 78 96 88
98 85 86 92 75
89 65 78 80 95
72 99 65 92 87
```

(This is not the exact sample data set for the assignment -- I'm not looking for the exact answer, just trying to understand; the set I have is not the data that will be used to test anyway.)

The first line is the number of assignments, the second line is the number of students, the third line is the student's names, and every subsequent line thereafter is each student's grade on each assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define NAME_LENGTH 10

void getGrades(FILE *ifp, int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus], char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH]);
void printGrades(int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus]);
void getStudents(FILE *ifp, int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH]);
void printStudents(int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH]);
void calcGrades(int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus], double final_grades[]);
void printFinalLetterGrades(int stus, double final_grades[]);
void printPercentageGrades(int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH], double final_grades[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *ifp = NULL;
    int assigns = 0;
    int stus = 0;
    int grades[assigns][stus];
    char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH];
    double final_grades[stus];


    if (argc != 2)
    {   
        if (argc < 2)
        {   
            printf("Input file not specified: ./<exec> <infile>");
            exit(1);

        }
        else if (argc > 2)
        {
            printf("Too many arguments: ./<exec> <infile>");
            exit(1);

        }

    }   

    ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: could not open %s.", argv[1]);
        exit(1);

    }


    fscanf(ifp, "%d%d", &assigns, &stus);

    //functions will go in this section

    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

I have opened the file and used fscanf to read the first two lines and assign them to the variables 'assigns' and 'stus' respectively, but I need to be able to iterate across the entirety of the data to be able to fill the two-dimensional arrays, 'grades' and 'students'in their respective functions (getGrades and getStudents).  How can I parse this data to make this possible?  I've considered using fgets to scan the entire data set in and then trying to parse the data using sscanf, but I feel like there's something much less complicated that I'm missing here and I can't figure out what it is.  Additionally, I'm worried about writing this in such a way that it will work with the sample data set that I have, but not with the data set they test with.

I'm about to tear my hair out, can anyone point me in the right direction?  Once I get to this point, I'm certain I can figure out the rest.  Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not going to work:

```
int assigns = 0;
int stus = 0;
int grades[assigns][stus];
```

These would be variable-length arrays, which is not what you typically want. However, if your assignment allows you to use them, it would be still wrong written like that, because they would be of size `0`.

Instead, find out the actual value of `assigns` and `stus` from the file. After that, allocate memory using `malloc` (or define your variable-length arrays at this point). Then, fill that memory with the data from the file. Then, close the file. After that, compute the report. Finally, at the end of the program, release the memory.

To read each value, the easiest is to forget about lines and simply read them one by one (since you know exactly how many they will be).